# uncheck "Post to facebook" as default in facebook comment social plugin

Tags: facebook

I want to have the possibility for users to post comments on a page on my website. But i dont want that peoples comments should show up on their wall.

So how can i have the checkbox "Post to facebook" unchecked as default? And even better, can i also remove it?

A picture of the box can be seen here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/653527/facebookcomment.png

Thanks!

Comment: There is an open bug for this, vote it up: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/193580584075592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an option for this currently.  You could request it by getting a hold of Facebook on their [developer group page](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/).